# IntellIj not displaying exceptions from @BeforeAll JUnit5

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit5

In IntelliJ, with a Springboot project (2.6.6) using JUnit 5, given the following test class, IntelliJ **doesn't display** exceptions occuring in the @BeforeAll method.

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class SpringTest {
    private Object OBJECT = new Object();

    @BeforeAll
    public static void before() {
        throw new RuntimeException("SpringTest.RuntimeException"); // replace by actual business code
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // Doesn't matter
        assertNotNull(this.OBJECT);
    }
```

#### Running the class within IntelliJ (only this class)

[image: run from IntelliJ, only one class]

#### Running the package of the test

[image: run from IntelliJ, whole test package]

When the @BeforeAll method is more complex, it's hard to understand that an exception occured, until you run the whole test package by chance.

In JUnit 4 with a @Before method, IntelliJ was showing test failure, with the stacktrace of the exception (which makes things easier to debug).

My pom.xml only dependencies are spring-boot-starter & spring-boot-starter-test.

**Is this a bug / Is there any solution to reproduce the old behaviour ?**

Stack:

- Spring boot 2.6.6 / JUnit 5
- IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1 Build #IU-221.5080.210
- OpenJDK_x64Temurin_11.0.14.1_1 / Maven-3.8.4

### Edit

As pointed out in the comment, to reproduce `@Before` of JUnit4, you should use `@BeforeEach` in Junit 5. In this case, IntelliJ will behave as before and display exceptions even when running only the given test class.

For the `@BeforeAll`, question is still pending.

### Edit 2

A bug has been opened for the `@BeforeAll` exceptions: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-292662

Comment: The equivalent of ˋ@Beforeˋ in JUnit 4 is ˋ@BeforeEachˋ in Jupiter aka JUnit 5. This should give you similar behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, using  `@BeforeEach` gives the same behaviour as before.

Comment: So you have to compare to JUnit 4‘s ˋ@BeforeClassˋ which should behave like ˋ@BeforeAllˋ.

Comment: you can follow the issue with '@BeforeAll' here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-292662

Answer (score 1):

Bug resolved in IntelliJ 2022.1.1 Preview.

See YouTrack: [IDEA-292662](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-292662)